# Unable to boot beagle bone black from 3rd partition

Tags: beagleboneblack

Unable to boot beagle bone blacke from 3 partioton.
I have following partition on sd card
boot   partition 1
rootfs partition 2
rootfs1 partition 3

I have two kernel, one kernel in rootfs and new kernel in rootfs1
I am able to boot kernel from rootfs partiotion
But If i edit uEnv.txt file to boot from partition 3.
It fails. It give error that init not found.

How to make beagle bone black boot from 3rd partiton (rootfs1)

Answer (score 0):

I studied uEnv.txt file care fully.

I did some research, I found that it is possible to make multiple partitions on sd card.

kernel image can be loaded from anywhere on partition.

so do this

=============== Load kernel image from Partition 3 =================

============== Including File system on partition 3 ================

console=ttyO0,115200n8

ipaddr=192.168.7.2

serverip=192.168.7.1

loadaddr=0x82000000

fdtaddr=0x88000000

loadfromsd=load mmc **0:3** ${loadaddr} /boot/uImage;load mmc **0:3** ${fdtaddr} /boot/am335x-boneblack.dtb

linuxbootargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} root=/dev/**mmcblk0p3** rw

uenvcmd=setenv autoload no; run loadfromsd; run linuxbootargs; bootm ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}

=====================================================================

**If you want to load kernel image from partition 2 then use code below**

=============== Load kernel image from Partition 2 ==================

=============== Including File system on partition 2 ================

console=ttyO0,115200n8

ipaddr=192.168.7.2

serverip=192.168.7.1

loadaddr=0x82000000

fdtaddr=0x88000000

loadfromsd=load mmc **0:2** ${loadaddr} /boot/uImage;load mmc **0:2** ${fdtaddr} /boot/am335x-boneblack.dtb

linuxbootargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} root=/dev/**mmcblk0p2** rw

uenvcmd=setenv autoload no; run loadfromsd; run linuxbootargs; bootm ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}

=====================================================================

conclusion :
On Beagle Bone Black
It is possible to make partition with any number that can fit kernel image and file system for linux